# sshfs giving "remote host has disconnected"

Tags: networking, ssh, vsftpd, sftp, sshfs

I am trying to mount an `sftp` connection into a folder using `sshfs` with the following command which throws an error.

```
~$ sshfs admin@example.com:/ testfo
remote host has disconnected
```

The same error happens if I SSH into the system and repeat the command by with `localhost`. This command also worked with another machine so therefore the issue is somewhere on the server.

```
~$ cat /var/log/auth.log

[...]

May 24 22:49:43 example sshd[20095]: Accepted publickey for admin from 24.111.222.33 port 47086 ssh2: RSA ad:xx:6e:xx:14:xx:bd:b5:xx:cb:66:xx:xx:xx:a3:ac
May 24 22:49:43 example sshd[20095]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user admin by (uid=0)
May 24 22:49:43 example systemd-logind[812]: Removed session 60.
May 24 22:49:43 example systemd-logind[812]: New session 61 of user admin.
May 24 22:49:44 example sshd[20143]: Received disconnect from 24.203.164.45: 11: disconnected by admin
May 24 22:49:44 example sshd[20095]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user admin
```

The `~/.ssh` directory is owned by admin since I saw that as a debugging attempt for a similar issue.

Additional information for future reference:

The issue is **not** with SSH itself, but with SFTP. This is manifested by the fact that SSH connections work correctly but SFTP always fails. Attempting to SFTP results in `Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server`

The issue is **not** related to login scripts outputted strings (e.g. `~/.bashrc`).

The issue is present from all users (including root).

Here is my sshd configuration (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`):

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

`sftp-server` package is installed. (`sudo apt-get install openssh-sftp-server`)

Comment: 1) Are you able to `sftp` there directly? What is the content of `~/.bashrc` or other startup files in your home directory of the server?

Comment: @Jakuje Hmm.. the issue seems to be in fact with sftp. Trying with filezilla gives `Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server`

Comment: 2) Can you `sftp` to different users? 3) How does you `sshd_config` on server look like? 4) How does your `~/.bashrc` look like?

Comment: @Jakuje Same 2) Nope.. Same error for all users. 3) http://pastebin.com/raw/ujNk3fVR 4) bashrc got nothing of relevance but here: http://pastebin.com/raw/mUD3DWmG

Comment: What you get from `which sftp-server`. Subsystem should be `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`. Do you have `sftp-server` installed? `apt-get install openssh-sftp-server`.

Comment: @Jakuje `openssh-sftp-server` is installed, however the which command returns nothing.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Done!

Comment: This can happen if the host key of the server has changed. Try a regular ssh connection and look for errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `Subsystem` value in `sshd_config` is wrong.

It should be `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` or `internal-sftp`. Try to modify the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to this value, restart the ssh service ans try once more.

Answer (score 16):

Old question, but the first one that comes up for this problem.

My issue was the server required key authentication, but I was running the command using `sudo` and specifying `-o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa`, meaning `~` was expanded to root's home, not mine.

Specifying the full path worked, and I imagine using `$HOME` would have too (because it would have expanded earlier).

Comment: Thanks, was able to mount with this tip.

Answer (score 7):

You'll get this error if the remote server is running Dropbear rather than OpenSSH.

> SSHFS uses SFTP, and Dropbear doesn't provide SFTP. So when you try
>   to use it, the Dropbear server sees a request for a subsystem that it
>   doesn't understand and drops the connection.

From here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363540/mount-a-filesystem-using-sshfs-using-the-dropbear-server-on-yocto-firmware

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it helps, but I had similar problem

```
remote host has disconnected
```

and after some googling&browsing I realised, that actually I connected ssh via different port.

So, for example, I had to connect via ssh (example, assuming port number 1234):

```
ssh username@example.com -p 1234
```

instead of standard ssh when port number is 22. So the same had to be used for sshfs connection:

```
sshfs username@example.com:/ ~/testfolder -p 1234
```

It solved my problem.

Comment: thank you very much. it works :)

Answer (score 1):

One more cause that happened to me was that the `dropbearmulti` binary itself lacked the string `/usr/libexec/sftp-server` which got lost somewhere around build 33600 of DD-WRT. Check if said binary mentions this file or it won't work even if it's present. I had to use a binary from build 33525 and make a launcher that kills the normal buggy dropbear, then runs this one. You create a symlink called `dropbear` pointing to `dropbearmulti`. You stop the current one with `stopservice sshd`, then run the working one. See in `ps` what the proper parameters look like.
It's best to have it on jffs (or unpack it to /tmp) so that you could still `umount` any drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to connect the host via ssh by itself:

```
ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

You may be prompted to save the key, you ned to type YES, not just a Y.  You should then be asked for the username and password for the user on that remote machine.

Use the one you are trying to do sshfs with, post back your results.

If you get a connection refused, I am guessing that you have not installed SSH on the remote computer.  Open ssh can be installed with this command, run on the remote computer:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

Comment: Yes I am able to ssh to it. "The same error happens if I SSH into the system[..]" Implied it. Server is setup correctly as far as I know

Comment: OK, I may be miss reading your comment, were you successfuly able to login with ssh, or as I read here:  "The same error happens if I SSH into the system[..]"

Comment: I can ssh to it just fine

Comment: OK, looking at your command line maybe you have an extra space?  I found this one on line I will send you the link.  
sshfs <username>@<ipaddress>:/remotepath ~/remoteserv  I found it here:  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-mount-a-remote-folder-using-ssh-on-ubuntu/  There are a bunch of other instructions but in your original question your command seems to have an extra space

Comment: I also do not see where you are connecting to your local system as a directory.  Your code my code to follow:
sshfs admin@example.com:/ testfo

Comment: My code: 
sshfs <username>@<ipaddress>:/remotepath ~/remoteserv

Comment: Do you see the extra space before testfo in your command?

Comment: The Stack Exchange network sites are very strict on the distinction between answers providing solutions, and comments. Comments showed up as a origin of spam, and heavy discussions not fitting the Stack Exchange model – this is why some reputation is required for posting them, showing you got familiar with the site's idea. This is not meant for annoying new users, but keeping the site's quality high. (See [Why and how are some answers deleted?](/help/deleted-answers))